# Xtratab control change tab pages according to menu option in C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress-windows-ui

I created one xtratab control.I created two tab pages in that named entry and reports. I created one more windows form and in that I created menu. in that menu I created two option bars name entry and report. when I click on entry in menu than that xtra tab page should come with entry tab selected. If I click on report in menu than that xtratab report page should open.

I searched in net but they told how to specify tab page in form while form is loading like `Tab.SelectedTabPage = xtraTabPage2;` But this is not suitable for my condition.

Comment: What do you mean by "But this is not suitable for my condition." ? Can you clarify what are you trying to accomplish in more details?

Comment: @FrustratedEveryday I will explain more clearly. I created one xtratab control.I created two tab pages in that named entry and reports. I created one more windows form and in that I created menu. in that menu I created two option bars name entry and report. when I click on entry in menu than that xtra tab page should come with entry tab selected. If I click on report in menu than that xtratab report page should open.

Comment: So do you want to change the selected tab through another form? You may want to consider to update your question :)

Comment: @ FrustratedEveryday, I updated My question like what you told

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to achive your goal is to set your `XtraTabControl`'s and it's tab member modifier to public. Then at your `Another Form`'s constructor, pass your `First Form` as a parameter.

Your `AnotherForm` should look like this:

```
private readonly Form1 _form1;

public AnotherForm(Form1 form1)
{
    _form1 = form1;
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _form1.xtraTabControl1.SelectedTabPage = _form1.xtraTabPage1;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _form1.xtraTabControl1.SelectedTabPage = _form1.xtraTabPage2;
}
```

Now call `AnotherForm` from your main form: `new AnotherForm(this).ShowDialog();`

If you don't want to set `xtraTabPage`'s modifier to public you can simply use `SelectedTabPageIndex` which is integer type.

[image]

Comment: what I have to mention in Programs.cs

Comment: error coming in program.cs that "there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter form1 of 'Form2.Form2(Form1)'. I created Form1 and in that created xtratab control and created two tab pages.all modifiers I changed to public as you told. I created Form2 and added the code what you wrote above.

Comment: I want to run Form2. In From2 according to the selected option only I have to run Form1 and open selected tab page. How to achieve  that

Comment: OK. I added  like what you told. It is opening Form1 and Form2. If I want to run Form2 Directly from program.cs what I have to do.

Comment: @vijay I was answering related to this question. You should open a new question for that.

Comment: @ FrustratedEveryday, I asked that question only see above my question. But what you gave solution is for me some what helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183075/discussion-between-vijay-and-frustratedeveryday).